# Some Domain Clients unable to access certain websites

Tags: website, domain

I have a small domain around 20 clients with a 2003 R2 SP2 DC.

Most of my clients can browse the internet freely and dont have a problem.
However a couple are reporting problems accessing certain sites. IE:
Hotmail, skyscanner, bbc news

They can browse the sites sometimes then other times they get 408\409 errors.

other machines in the domain can access these sites.

I have cleared out dns cache on these machines modified external dns servers on the DC still to no avail.

The main issue is the person not able to access skyscanner uses it several times a day to book flights for employess going on leave or returning to work.

both clients are running XP SP3 though one machine is getting change for one running win7 shortly.

Any advice greatly appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have since discovered this is not a DNS issue as I first thought.
I have changed service providers and the MTU is different.

In my Firewall I have changed the MTU vlaue from default (1500) to a value of 1492.

This has cured my problems and also seems to have sped up the internet.